# html links faded with hidden tables

Tags: html, css, layout

Unfortunately, I’m not able to share my code, but I think I can describe my situation to the point that you can understand what is going on.

I have a html page with three tables. I use style commands (@media only screen and min-width or max-width) which hides two of the three tables depending on the browser width. This works like a charm.

I have links to other pages; this is where the issue arises. When hovering over the link, the link color is not normal. The color is slightly faded. This is true no matter what I do. I could use style to change the link on hover. I could leave the link to the default. I can use any color. It is always slightly faded (i.e. red appears slightly pinkish).

I hope that description is sufficient and makes sense. Does anyone have any ideas why this would be?

Comment: Could be `opacity` setting in the css. Can you at least share the css for the affected element(s). You really should reproduce the symptom in some code you can share.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Instead of trying to describe what the code is doing, please provide an example of the code which demonstrates the problem.  For HTML/CSS issues you can even include a [runnable snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) as a live demonstration.  This will allow us to see the problem, rather than relying on only your attempt to describe what you suspect the problem might be.  For tips and information on asking a question, please also see [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Wow. I'm embarrassed. It was an opacity issue on one of the hidden tables.  I can't believe i missed that. In the future I'll try to be more thorough. Thank you for your assistance. I really, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

It was an opacity issue. Issue resolved.